Is there a Prüfer domain that is a UFD but not a PID?
An integral domain $R$ is called a Prüfer domain if every non-zero finitely generated ideal $I$ of $R$ is invertible. Many equivalent characterizations can be found here.

Question. Is there a Prüfer domain $R$ that is also a unique factorization domain (UFD) but not a principal ideal domain (PID)?

I guess that such $R$ exists as the definition says nothing about the ideals that are not finitely generated. It is well-known that a Dedekind domain or a Bézout domain that is a UFD is a PID, so such $R$ must be neither a Dedekind domain nor a Bézout domain. But I already had a hard time to find a Prüfer domain that is neither a Dedekind domain nor a Bézout domain. An example is $\operatorname{Int}(\mathbb{Z})$, the ring of integer-valued polynomials with rational coefficients. This ring is Prüfer (see here) but not noetherian (so not a Dedekind domain). It is not a Bézout domain as the ideal $(2,X)$ is not principal. Unfortunately, it is also not UFD as $X(X-1)=2\cdot\dfrac{X(X-1)}{2}$ is a factorization of $X(X-1)$ into different irreducibles.
Thank you for any help in advance.

Did you check https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/ ?

@MartinBrandenburg Ah yes thanks, I forgot to mention it. There are no results with the given conditions.

Let $R$ be a Prüfer domain which is also a UFD. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal of $R$. Then $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a valuation ring which is also a UFD. As valuation rings are Bezout domains, this implies that $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a PID.
As $$\dim R = \sup_{\mathfrak{p}\in \mathrm{Spec}(R)} \dim R_{\mathfrak{p}}$$
This implies that $R$ has dimension $\leq 1$. Finally, a UFD of dimension at most one is a PID.

This result is cool. Thanks!

The software at DaRT is actually able to explain a proof for this, but it's not available for everyone's use yet.  The explanation probably boils down to this anyway :)
